# Passing data from MySQL to Vue.js data property

Tags: javascript, mysql, vue.js

I have some data that I get from MySQL and I want to put it into a vue.js data property so that I can iterate over it with v-for.

What format should I choose (json or array?) and what do I have to do so that the data is available in vue.js?

```
<?php
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM kurse;';
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if($resultCheck > 0) {

    $termineObj = new stdClass();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      echo $termineObj->datum = $row['datum'];
      $termineObj->uhrzeitvon = $row['uhrzeitvon'];
      $termineObj->uhrzeitbis = $row['uhrzeitbis'];
      $termineObj->freieplaetze = $row['freieplaetze'];

      $termine = json_encode($termineObj);
      echo $termine;
    }
  }
?>

...


<script>var app4 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-4',
  data: {
    termine: termine,
    },
  delimiters: ["((","))"],
  methods: {
    flipstate:function(){
      console.log('flipped');
    }
  },
})</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you should use `json_encode()` on the PHP side in order to convert your data array into an array that javascript can use.

Second, you have two options for actually using it:

a) place the JSON-encoded array/object directly into the data attribute you want, e.g.

```
<?php
    $data = array();
    //parse query results, insert into $data
?>

<script>
    var app4 = new Vue({
        el: '#app-4',
        data: {
            target_attr: <?=json_encode($data)?>
        },
        . . .
    });
</script>
```

b) Use an ajax call to insert the data from JSON, e.g.

**Your PHP file**

```
<?php
    $data = array();
    //parse query results, insert into $data
    echo json_encode(array('returned_data'=>$data));
?>
```

**Your Javascript**

```
<script>
    var app4 = new Vue({
        el: '#app-4',
        data: {
            target_attr: [] //or {} if you are expecting an object
        },
        mounted: {
            var vue_instance = this;
            //using jQuery for simplicity
            $.post('/path/to/your/php/file', {some: 'data if needed'}, function(data) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                vue_instance.target_attr = obj.returned_data;
            });
        },
        . . .
    });
</script>
```

Getting the actual code you will need for everything to work will be left as an exercise, but I hope this pushes you in the right direction. Good luck!